# How can I fetch total of Qty of Buy and Sale in month of July in single sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to find total buy and sell in single row for the specific month.
Below is the table
[image: This is the table]

---

Comment: Have you tried to write any query at all ? Please avoid using image. Use formatted text

Answer (score 3):

**Month()** function will help to group the month values.

```
SELECT
YEAR(TrDate) SaleYear, 
MONTH(TrDate) SaleMonth,
   SUM(CASE WHEN trType = 'B' THEN Qty END)) as TotalBuy,
   SUM(CASE WHEN trType = 'S' THEN Qty END)) as TotalSale
   FROM TableName 
   GROUP BY YEAR(TrDate), MONTH(TrDate)
```